# MURA CMS: How to get the fileId from filename of an uploaded file?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, mura

I have a spreadsheet uploaded via Mura's file manager. I need to read that file using ColdFusion and for that I need a query object returned via the `read()` method of Mura's file manager bean. In order to call the `read()` method I will need the `fileID`. The problem is I don't have that. I have the filename and it will always be the same. I can't use `$.content` because the file wasn't uploaded to the current page. Any ideas?

Basically any ideas about how can I use this

```
<cfset file = #$.getBean('filemanager').readMeta(item.getFileID()).filename#>
```

That code does not work for me because it refers to `item.getFileID` and as I am not in a loop I am unable to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the Mura content node that holds the file will always have the same name, you can load the content bean based on that name.

```
bean = $.getBean("content").loadBy(name={name}, siteID={siteID})
```

(siteid is optional)

If there are more content nodes with the same name, the call loadby function will return an array off all beans.

More info on loading content beans:
http://docs.getmura.com/v6/back-end/base-mura-objects-beans/loading-beans/

Once you've got the right content bean, you can ask for it's fileId.

```
bean.getFileId()
```